# python group id panel data

Tags: python, panel

I'm relatively new to Python, I have a dataset as
follows:

```
hhid psid year
 1    1   1989
 1    1   1991
 1    1   1993
 1    1   2000
 1    2   1989
 1    2   1991
 1    2   1993
 1    2   2000
 2    1   1989
 2    1   1991
 2    1   1993
 2    1   2000

 ... ...  ...
hhid=household ID
psid=personal ID within a household
```

And my question is how to create a personal ID (say
uid) applied to the whold panel dataset that looks
like:

```
hhid psid year uid
 1    1   1989  1
 1    1   1991  1
 1    1   1993  1
 1    1   2000  1
 1    2   1989  2
 1    2   1991  2
 1    2   1993  2
 1    2   2000  2
 2    1   1989  3
 2    1   1991  3
 2    1   1993  3
 2    1   2000  3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you load your dataset into a pandas dataframe, `df`, then you can try:

`df['uid'] = df['hhid'].astype(str) + '_' + df['psid'].astype(str)`

which yields:

`+------+------+------+-----+
| hhid | psid | year | uid |
+------+------+------+-----+
|    1 |    1 | 1989 | 1_1 |
|    1 |    1 | 1991 | 1_1 |
|    1 |    1 | 1993 | 1_1 |
|    1 |    1 | 2000 | 1_1 |
|    1 |    2 | 1989 | 1_2 |
|    1 |    2 | 1991 | 1_2 |
|    1 |    2 | 1993 | 1_2 |
|    1 |    2 | 2000 | 1_2 |
|    2 |    1 | 1989 | 2_1 |
|    2 |    1 | 1991 | 2_1 |
|    2 |    1 | 1993 | 2_1 |
|    2 |    1 | 2000 | 2_1 |
+------+------+------+-----+`

Answer (score 0):

There must be an easier way but i went with this:

```
combos = zip(df.hhid.tolist(), df.psid.tolist())
maps = zip(range(1, len(set(combos))+1), sorted(set(combos), key=combos.index))
final_maps = {k: v for v, k in maps}

df['uid'] = zip(df['hhid'],df['psid'])
df['uid'] = df['uid'].apply(lambda x: final_maps[x])
```